# Adding to ObservableCollection Alphabetically

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid

I have an `ObservableCollection` that contains `Companies`. I want to add a `Company` to the `ObservableCollection` and I do so like this;

```
Companies.Add(newCompany);
CompanyICollectionView.Refresh();
```

This does add the `Company` to the `ObservableCollection`, however it adds it to the very bottom of the `DataGrid`. I would like the `Company` to be added in the correct position in the `ObservableCollection` alphabetically. I tried to use `SortDescription` after adding to the `Companies`;

```
companyDataGrid.Items.SortDescriptions.Add(new SortDescription("CompanyName", ListSortDirection.Descending));
```

however this was very slow and also resulted in some strange ordering (`Companies` beginning with 'O' were at the top). How can I add in a `Company`so that it automatically comes in listed alphabetically?

Comment: Maybe those companies that "begin with 'O'", were actualy a zero?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try to use linq method:

```
Companies=new ObservableCollection<T>(Companies.OrderBy(i=>i));
```

Please note that the order of items in collection is not modified after the `OrderBy()` method call.  You should say: `Companies=Companies<T>(Companies.OrderBy(i=>i));`

**For example:**

Sorting in alphabetical order. You should *explicitly* say using lambda expression what property(`FirstName` in my example) should be used to sort:

Your model:

```
public class Person
{
    public int IdPerson { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
}
```

I suggest you to use full property implementation:

```
private ObservableCollection<Person> persons=new ObservableCollection<Person>();
public ObservableCollection<Person> Persons
{
  get { return persons; }
  set { persons = value;
        persons = new ObservableCollection<Person>(persons.OrderBy(x => x.Name));
        OnPropertyChanged("Persons");
      }
```

}

Every time when you add new item, your collection will be reordered(in my view, it is not good approach):

```
Persons.Add(new Person() { IdPerson=1, FirstName="Bill"});
Persons.Add(new Person() { IdPerson = 2, FirstName = "Jon" });
Persons.Add(new Person() { IdPerson = 3, FirstName = "Joseph" });
Persons.Add(new Person() { IdPerson = 4, FirstName = "Ben" });
Persons.Add(new Person() { IdPerson = 5, FirstName = "Magnus" });
```

**or you can sort the view of the collection rather that sorting the collection itself. In my view it is better:**

```
<yourView.Resources>
    <CollectionViewSource x:Key="ItemListViewSource" Source="{Binding Persons}">
        <CollectionViewSource.SortDescriptions>
            <scm:SortDescription PropertyName="FirstName" />
        </CollectionViewSource.SortDescriptions>
    </CollectionViewSource>
</yourView.Resources>
```

Comment: @downvoter, why do you downvote? it is really interesting to know the reason. :)

Comment: I didn't downvote, but the code in your answer is invalid, that's probably a reason. `Companies=Companies<T>(Companies.OrderBy(i=>i));` makes no sense.

Comment: @Shazi oops, sorry that I've not tested. Now I've tested and it works.

Comment: @StepUp thanks for your answer. I get an exception - `At least one object must implement IComparable`. Any help? What would I replace `x => x` with in a `CompanyModel`? CompanyName? This is what I have tried: `Companies = new ObservableCollection<CompanyModel>(Companies.OrderBy(x => x));`

Comment: @StepUP is that enough? Does the fault lie with `x => x`?

Comment: @CBreeze I figured out your problem! You should explicitly say what property should be used to sort. Please, see my updated answer.

Comment: @StepUp Thanks for all your help... the collection is sorted fine, however it still adds the new company to the bottom, even if I sort the collection AFTER adding the company in

Comment: @StepUp How can I sort it programatically after adding a new item to the collection?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/108487/discussion-between-stepup-and-cbreeze).

Comment: @CBreeze When you add new item to `Persons`, not `persons`, your collection will be sorted programmatically.

Answer (score 0):

@Cbreeze
It was quiet simple as @Steup already shared above just to add on ,

```
   // ascending
collection = new ObservableCollection<string>(collection.OrderBy(a => a));

// descending
collection = new ObservableCollection<string>(collection.OrderByDescending(a => a));
```

if you want something else let us know will try to help but please be clear to your question

@Stepup you are correct i do not know why some one downvoted you